# Number of Zeros of an equation

Tags: complex-analysis

Why is it that the equation $z^5=0$ has five zeros, seeing as
 $z=0$ is the only solution? (When $z$ is a complex number) The context for this is Rouche's theorem.

Comment: The zeros are counted according to their multiplicity. Here the multiplicity is 5.

Comment: You have to count zeros with multiplicity.  It only has one root but with multiplicity five.

Comment: Another viewpoint is that for small $\epsilon>0$, the equation $z^5=\epsilon$ has exactly 5 distinct roots, so $\epsilon=0$ can be considered as some sort of limiting behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The equation has five zeros, but they are **not unique**. We say that the solution $z=0$ has **multiplicity five**, meaning there are five such solutions.

This all relates to the Fundamental theorem of Algebra which says that a polynomial of degree $n$ has exactly $n$ roots (counting multiplicity). This could also be formulated as "a polynomial of degree $n$ has $\leq n$ unique roots", but this claim is less strong.